# Python, protocol buffers, and getting nested messages and repeated fields to work

Tags: python, protocol-buffers

I am trying to submit a response using protocol buffers in python.  Below is the structure.

```
message BidResponse {
  message Ad {
    optional string html_snippet = 1;
    message TemplateParameter {
      optional string parameter_value = 1;
      optional string blank_ad_parameter_value = 8;
      optional string buyer_creative_id = 2;
      optional string click_through_url = 3;
      optional int32 left = 4;
      optional int32 right = 5;
      optional int32 top = 6;
      optional int32 bottom = 7;
      optional int32 backup_index = 9;
    };
    repeated TemplateParameter template_parameter = 13;
    repeated string click_through_url = 4;
    repeated int32 vendor_type = 5;
    message AdSlot {
      required int32 id = 1;
      required int64 max_cpm_micros = 2;
    }
    repeated AdSlot adslot = 3;
  }
  repeated Ad ad = 2;
  optional int32 processing_time_ms = 4;
}
```

Now, below is my python code that I am trying to submit.

```
ms = (time.time() - start)*1000
bid_response = realtime_bidding_pb2.BidResponse()
bid_response.processing_time_ms = int(ms)
ad = bid_response.Ad()
ad.html_snippet = """<img src='http://cdn.test.com/test.gif' />"""
ad.click_through_url = """test.com"""

adslot = ad.AdSlot()
adslot.id = adslots_id[0]             
adslot.max_cpm_micros=150000000
```

When I submit using the below:

```
'Content-Type', 'application/octet-stream'
bid_response.SerializeToString()
```

All that is returned is the bid_response.processing_time_ms.

I suspect I am nt doing repeated and messages correctly.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I remember spending a while hunting this down in my python code a while back. You can find the documentation for the fields interface in python here : http://code.google.com/apis/protocolbuffers/docs/reference/python-generated.html#fields.

What you want is the `add` member function - using that your code would look like this:

```
ms = (time.time() - start)*1000
bid_response = realtime_bidding_pb2.BidResponse()
bid_response.processing_time_ms = int(ms)
ad = bid_response.ad.add()
ad.html_snippet = """<img src='http://cdn.test.com/test.gif' />"""
ad.click_through_url = """test.com"""

adslot = ad.adslot.add()
adslot.id = adslots_id[0]             
adslot.max_cpm_micros=150000000
```

Comment: Wow...that kinda worked!  But for hte ad.clickthoru it is repeated.  I get this error.     '"%s" in protocol message object.' % proto_field_name)
AttributeError: Assignment not allowed to repeated field "click_through_url" in protocol message object.  How to I make click though repeated?  Thanks

Comment: Thanks..got it...haha...repeated is a list and just use append.

Answer (score 0):

Did you read [the documentation](http://code.google.com/apis/protocolbuffers/docs/pythontutorial.html)? It's quite clear.

You should replace

```
ad = bid_response.Ad()
```

with

```
ad = bid_response.ad.add()
```

and likewise for AdSlot.

Comment: Here's a slightly more appropriate documentation link: http://code.google.com/apis/protocolbuffers/docs/reference/python-generated.html#fields

Comment: it is the new document here for proto3. https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/python-generated#repeated-fields